# Vue.set two different object properties with the same reference

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add an object into an array using Vue.set function, but it adds the item to another object with the same array property.

```
data() {
    return {
      ...
      form: {
        ...
        client_a: {
           ...
           items: []
        },
        client_b: {
           ...
           items: []
        },
      }
    };
  },
```

When I do: (note that I'm adding an item to **client_a**.items)

```
this.$set(this.form.client_a.items, 'key', { prop1: '', prop2: '' })
```

Then **client_b**.items var has the same value of client_a

```
console.log(this.form.client_b.items)
```

Outputs

```
[
   'key': { prop1: '', prop2: '' }
]
```

The expected result of this.form.**client_b**.items is

```
[]
```

as I don't added anything into it

Code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-fast-bjvyr

Comment: You initialize both clients with the same reference to `this.base_client`.

Comment: I guess you're are using the same function as reference. Did you try to clone the function?

Comment: @str Object.assign clears the reference, or not?

Comment: @RodrigoVinicius can you provide an example? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: The `Object.assign` ensures that `client_a` and `client_b` are different objects but they still share the same `functions` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @skirtle points out, the `base_client.functions`-property is the same array.
A simple fix in `beforeMount()`:

```js
beforeMount() {
  this.form.client_a = {
    ...this.base_client,
    functions: []
  }
  this.form.client_b = {
    ...this.base_client,
    functions: []
  }
  this.form.functions = [
    {
      key: "key-1",
      name: "Test"
    }
  ];
}
```

Not too elegant, but should work. Another way to do it is to make `base_client` a method with a return value, where you generate a new `returns`-array every time.